# random sprite movement and collision python

Tags: python, pygame, collision-detection, sprite

I am making a pacman style game using python in pygame. At the moment I am creating the ghosts/monsters that pacman has to avoid around the maze. I have created these and tried to add random movement a collision detection so they go around the maze and not just all over the screen. The code for these monsters is bellow. My question is that the `Monster` seem to slightly jump about and barely move, how can i get the, to smoothly go through the maze like the pacman ghosts? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could not test your code on my computer because for some reason, python returns a few errors. But let me give analyzing your code a shot.

The problem seems to arise from these two lines:

```
self.rect.x += random.randint(-1,1)
self.rect.y += random.randint(-1,1)
```

which are underneath your `update(self)` function.

Since you set your monsters to "update" every screen refresh, your monsters will move one pixel up, down, left or right randomly each time you call update. Your "update" function calls a random number from -1 to 1 every single time. So, your monsters either move by +1 or 0 or -1 pixels every screen refresh vertically and horizontally. As a result, they appear wiggly and not moving anywhere at all.

What you want for a smooth movement is for your "update" function to move your monster in a single constant direction.

I am not sure about the best way to go about your game, but here is what I suggest: (My codes are just a guide, they might contain errors)

Give the Monster class a variable or property called "dir" which stands for direction. Upon initiating your class, give "dir" a random value from 1 to 4 (which stands for Up, Down, Left and Right)

`self.dir = random.randint(1,4)`

Then, in your "update(self)" function, write some `if` statements like this:

```
if self.dir == 1: #Moving up
    self.rect.y+=1;

if self.dir == 2: #Moving down
    self.rect.y-=1;

if self.dir == 3: #Moving left
    self.rect.x-=1;

if self.dir == 4: #Moving right
    self.rect.x+=1;
```

That way, your monsters only move up down left or right in one direction at a time.

With this, I think you'd have to modify your "check for collision" code as well. Make your code change your monster's direction depending on which part of the wall it hit.

Hope this helps! :)

**Edit:**

Your second issue was that your monsters did not collide with walls properly. Here is your code:

```
if self.rect.x > -1: # Moving right; Hit the left side of the wall
    self.rect.right = wall.rect.left
if self.rect.x < 0: # Moving left; Hit the right side of the wall
    self.rect.left = wall.rect.right
if self.rect.y < -1: # Moving down; Hit the top side of the wall
    self.rect.bottom = wall.rect.top
if self.rect.y > 0: # Moving up; Hit the bottom side of the wall
    self.rect.top = wall.rect.bottom
```

I find it peculiar that your check the direction of your monsters based on its location. Take `if self.rect.x > -1:` as an example. `"self.rect.x"` is actually the x-coordinate of your monster. So this does not indicate the direction of your monster at all. So I don't think you can use `self.rect.x` or `self.rect.y` in your `if` statements for collision.

Instead, consider using the "dir" I just recommended you.
I'll change the first line for you and you can do the rest of it.

```
if self.dir == 4: # Moving right; Hit the left side of the wall
self.rect.right = wall.rect.left
```

After that, your monster will stop because it will try to move in the same direction again but this code will stop it. So, you have to change its direction randomly again. Just make sure that it does not choose the same direction again.  I'll leave this as a puzzle for you for now.

**Edit 2:**

You mentioned that your collision does not work for top and bottom.

Took a while before I got where your error is ;)

```
if self.dir == 1: #Moving up
    self.rect.y+=2;

if self.dir == 2: #Moving down
    self.rect.y-=2;
```

I think you interchanged your `y+=2` and `y=-2`. So your moving up and down motions were interchanged.

Comment: Oh right i understand! yes the sprites now move smoothly thank you! And it may not have worked on yours due to it having images that you don't have, I have tried to changed the collision by putting different values in it, checking for a left collision seems to work, but no other direction! Could you suggest any values? Thanks again!

Comment: I have added the whole of the game to the code for convenience, if you change the image names in the #loadbackground and self.image in the monster class to any image you have in the same file as the code then the code will work fine, thank you again!

Comment: No, the error is not about the images because I placed images of my own. The error says `"super() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)"`

Comment: I have worked on this and right and left collisions, seem to work but not top or bottom. If there anything you could suggest where i may have gone wrong? The updated collision code is in the code. Thank you.

Comment: Just a tip, you only have to add this line once in your code `self.dir = random.randint(1,4)` right after the `if` block. I have added my answer again.

Comment: No problem! :) just glad I could help.